# Local host connecting error

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I want run the asp.net application in chrome with using IDE visual studio 2015. (we created it by using visual studio 2017 with another PC) but when i tried to run it using with google chrome its saying that,

**" This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
Search Google for localhost 51383 FrontPage
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED "**

can anyone help me to fix this ?

[three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQfEq.png)

[four](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGRWz.png)

Comment: Did you search Google for that error message?

Comment: Try this: In solution Explorer, go to the sln file(or I suppose project file), right click on it and open properties. Now, try changing port number here(You may have to change some other settings too if this does not work) and try running it again..

Comment: thank u very much for helping!!!  but its not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Check your asp.net server(development server) port number?

```
In Solution Explorer, click the name of the site.
In the Project menu, click Properties.
Click the Web tab.
Check the port number there.
If it is different, Click Specific port and enter a port number.
Now use the port number and it should work.
```

Comment: thank u very much for helping me. but those port numbers are same

Comment: Can you change the port number to new port number, save and rebuild the solution ?

Comment: I did it "This site can’t be reached

localhost refused to connect.
Search Google for localhost 54383 FrontPage
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Comment: Can you attach screenshot of all the port numbers? (Project Properties, asp.net developer server /IIS express and browser)

Comment: sure I can. but I don't know how to attach them

Comment: You should attach to your question. There is an image icon and use them.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQfEq.png     https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGRWz.png

Comment: Share your project port details also?

Comment: I cant attach more pictures because of the exceeding capacity of the question.

Comment: Share the port number ? You should be able to upload the image in google drive or onedrive and share the link.

Comment: can you give some different port number in the project file and check?

Comment: I checked it :(

Comment: Are you sure, you running and accessing the application in your local machine only?

Comment: yeah I'm sure that I'm running and accessing the application in my local machine only

Comment: finally I changed my pc control panel Items>Network setting and sharing>local area connection>properties... check internet protocol version 4....... now there is an error msg when I'm running application. It's saying " unable to launch the IIS Express Web Server"

Comment: Try disconnecting n/w then. I couldn't really understand what is going wrong in your end ? Can we do kind of screenshare via join.me or something similar to sort out this issue ?